# How to combine two decision tree object?

Tags: python, random-forest, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I have selected some of the decision tree objects(using estimators) from random forest classifiers. Now I would like to combine the selected decision tree object into a single object. Can someone suggest me how to merge the selected Decision tree objects from random forest?

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't. If you have two prefit estimators, you can either retrain a single estimator on the data, or you can use both and combine the predictions using weighted averaging or some other method

Comment: What do you mean by "merge" or "combine" in this case?

Comment: I have selected some specific decision tree from the random forest. Now I would like to get a random forest with these specifically selected decision trees. Is there any possible way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [VotingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#voting-classifier) in order to combine multiple estimators.
Decision trees only support a hard classification output (`.predict`), not probabilities ones (`.predict_proba`), so it can only be used with hard voting (majority voting).
You are going to need 3 or more trees for majority voting to make much sense.

Random Forests also combine decision tree predictions by majority voting.